# Samba Shares after upgrading to 19.04

Tags: samba, 19.04

after upgrading to 19.04, I can no longer access my samba shares from my windows server I get the message network dropped connection on reset

Answer (score 0):

It turns out Samba was no longer connecting because smbv1 wasn't enabled I hope this helps anyone else with the issue